# My nav isnt where I want it to be

Tags: html, css

If you run the code you'll see I have a header with text at the top left but i want my nav to be at the top right but it only appears as far as the bottom of the header. Ive tried inspecting the element and trying to work it out but no joy. Here is my code.

```css
 html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      padding: auto;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .ct {
      font-weight: lighter;
    }
    
    header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 75px;
      width: 100%;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a537a 1%,#204377 100%);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 35px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
    
    header h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: Roboto;
      color: #ffffff;
      line-height: 75px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      font-weight: 400;
      letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    }
    
    header nav ul{
      float: right;
    }
    
    header nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CT Designs</title>
        <!-- Stylesheets-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <!-- Fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
    
     <body>
      <header>
        <h1><span class="ct">CT</span> Designs</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About Me</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
     </body>
    
     </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `float: left` to `header h1` and that will allow your nav list to float to the right as you've specified.

But I would use flexbox on the header with `justify-content: space-between` to push the elements to the left/right, then use `align-items` to vertically align the header content.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: auto;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.ct {
  font-weight: lighter;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a537a 1%, #204377 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 35px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

header h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 75px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}

header nav ul {
  float: right;
}

header nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1><span class="ct">CT</span> Designs</h1>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Home</li>
      <li>About Me</li>
      <li>Projects</li>
      <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is due to the float. If you use absolute positioning, it will work - adjust to fit.

```css
html, body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
      padding: auto;
    }
    
    h1 {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    ul {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    .ct {
      font-weight: lighter;
    }
    
    header {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 75px;
      width: 100%;
      background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3a537a 1%,#204377 100%);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 9px 35px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    }
    
    header h1 {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-family: Roboto;
      color: #ffffff;
      line-height: 75px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      font-weight: 400;
      letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    }
    
    header nav ul{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      color: white;
    }
    
    header nav ul li {
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>CT Designs</title>
        <!-- Stylesheets-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
        <!-- Fonts-->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,100i,300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>
    
     <body>
      <header>
        <h1><span class="ct">CT</span> Designs</h1>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About Me</li>
            <li>Projects</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </header>
     </body>
    
     </html>
```